# In R, is it possible to suppress "Note: no visible binding for global variable"?

Tags: r, reference-class

I'm wondering if its possible to suppress these outputs in R which are cluttering up the console:

```
Note: no visible binding for global variable '.->ConfigString' 
Note: no visible binding for '<<-' assignment to 'ConfigString'
```

Here is the code (its a simple ReferenceClass to store configuration for an R project):

```
# Reference Class to store configuration
Config <- setRefClass("Config",
  fields = list(    
    ConfigString = "character"
    ),
    methods = list(
        # Constructor
        initialize = function() {
            ConfigString <<- "Hello, World!"
        }
  )
)
```

**What I have tried so far**

I've tried ever combination and permutation of predefining the variables, pre-setting them to null, etc, but R is still stubbornly printing hundreds of "No Visible Binding" notes in my source code.

Is anyone wiser than I when it comes to the internals of R?

**Update 1**

I've tried changing `Config <-` to `Config <<-`, and that gets rid of the second extraneous note. The first extraneous note is still present, however.

**Update 2**

I'm beginning to lose heart, even [sample code by John Chambers](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/methods/ReferenceClasses) generates more of these horrible, extraneous notes.

**Update 3**

These notes occur in Revolution R v7.0, but don't occur in RStudio. It appears as if Revolution R v7.0 is calling `R CMD check`, which is normally only used when preparing packages, so these notes can safely be ignored.

**Update 4**

[Hadley Wickhams code also generates these notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439256/how-can-i-handle-r-cmd-check-no-visible-binding-for-global-variable-notes-when). Apparently, it is possible to eliminate them using `utils::globalVariables`, however, this doesn't seem to work on the newer ReferenceClasses. Even if it were at all possible to use them, Hadley states:

> globalVariables is a hideous hack and I will never use it.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9439256/324364)?

Comment: If you had read what I linked to, you wouldn't have referred to these as "horrible, extraneous errors". Horrible, maybe. Extraneous, for sure. Errors? Not even close.

Comment: @joran You're right, I've changed "error" to "note".

Comment: Adding something like `ConfigString <- NULL` right in the beginning of the function (before you use these variables) also makes the notes go away.

Comment: @Tyler Rinker You're right, this fixed the issue. I've added an answer below, I wisht here was some way to give your answer 10 votes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All credit to @Tyler Rinker for this answer.

To eliminate these notes, prefix the source code above with this:

```
# Intent:
#   This function suppresses the following notes generated by "R CMD check":
#   - "Note: no visible binding for global variable '.->ConfigString'"
#   - "Note: no visible binding for '<<-' assignment to 'ConfigString'"
# Usage:
#   Add the following right in the beginning of the .r file (before the Reference
#   class is defined in the sourced .r file):
#   suppressBindingNotes(c(".->ConfigString","ConfigString"))
suppressBindingNotes <- function(variablesMentionedInNotes) {
    for(variable in variablesMentionedInNotes) {
        assign(variable,NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv)       
    }
}

suppressBindingNotes(c(".->ConfigString","ConfigString"))
```

In addition, sometimes Revolution R might need to be restarted if it has been running for a long time.

Comment: Is this less "hideous" than using `utils::globalVariables`?

Comment: I believe this is worse, because those objects will be accessible with `pkg:::` while variables used in `globalVariables()` won't, so this solution will create a bit of user facing mess. I'm respectfully downvoting this.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this command.

> compiler::setCompilerOptions(suppressAll = TRUE)

This works for me to suppress the messages like

> Note: no visible binding for global variable ...
>   Note: no visible binding for global function definition ...